# Capture screenshot from Blackberry 10 Simulator to PC

Tags: screenshot, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

How can I capture screenshot from Blackberry 10 Simulator to my PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look around the VMWare tool, not the BB10 image:
http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_capture.html